# Maven. Snapshot updates (first download) don't work

Tags: java, maven, snapshot

I created remote repositories (release and snapshot) from local repository. Both new remote reposotories were added yo groups/public.
I try to make project build from scratch and my new local repo is empty.

During snapshot downloading I get following error:

```
[WARNING] The POM for net.homecredit.ws:integration.tests.base.ru:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

...

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project webclient-ru: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.company.ws:webclient-ru:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:

Could not find artifact net.company.ws:integration.tests.base.ru:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

Output of dir command in snapshot-repo in directory with problem snapshot:

```
Dir C:\Nexus\sonatype-work\nexus\storage\rep-snapshots\net\company\ws\integration.tests.base.ru\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
28.02.2011  11:28    <DIR>          .
28.02.2011  11:28    <DIR>          ..
28.02.2011  11:28                 0 1
25.02.2011  11:50            15 551 integration.tests.base.ru-1.0.0-20100429-030459-1.jar
28.02.2011  11:19                32 integration.tests.base.ru-1.0.0-20100429-030459-1.jar.md5
28.02.2011  11:19                40 integration.tests.base.ru-1.0.0-20100429-030459-1.jar.sha1
25.02.2011  11:50             1 462 integration.tests.base.ru-1.0.0-20100429-030459-1.pom
28.02.2011  11:19                32 integration.tests.base.ru-1.0.0-20100429-030459-1.pom.md5
28.02.2011  11:19                40 integration.tests.base.ru-1.0.0-20100429-030459-1.pom.sha1
25.02.2011  11:50            15 551 integration.tests.base.ru-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
28.02.2011  11:19                32 integration.tests.base.ru-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.md5
28.02.2011  11:19                40 integration.tests.base.ru-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.sha1
25.02.2011  11:50             1 462 integration.tests.base.ru-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
28.02.2011  11:19                32 integration.tests.base.ru-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom.md5
28.02.2011  11:19                40 integration.tests.base.ru-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom.sha1
25.02.2011  18:26               794 maven-metadata.xml
28.02.2011  11:19                32 maven-metadata.xml.md5
28.02.2011  11:19                40 maven-metadata.xml.sha1
```

After some tries I put files with both possible names. Their content is the same.

My settings.xml for maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <!-- localRepository
  | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
  |
  | Default: ~/.m2/repository
    -->
    <localRepository>C:\Donz\Projects\Maven\repository</localRepository>
        <servers>
        <server>
            <id>hci-private-releases</id>
            <username>deployment</username>
            <password>deployment123</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>hci-private-snapshots</id>
            <username>deployment</username>
            <password>deployment123</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>thirdparty</id>
            <username>deployment</username>
            <password>deployment123</password>
        </server>
    </servers>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>central</name>
                    <url>http://rep-pc.company.ru:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>public</id>
                    <name>Local repository for public group</name>
                    <url>http://rep-pc.company.ru:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>public-snapshots</id>
                    <name>Local repository for public snapshots group</name>
                    <url>http://rep-pc.company.ru:8081/nexus/content/repositories/rep-snapshots</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>hci-plugins-releases</id>
                    <name>Maven plugins repository</name>
                    <url>http://rep-pc.company.ru:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>hci-plugins-snapshots</id>
                    <name>Maven plugins releases repository</name>
                    <url>http://rep-pc.company.ru:8081/nexus/content/repositories/rep-snapshots</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <mirrors>
        <!-- mirror
        | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository. The repository that
        | this mirror serves has an ID that matches the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used
        | for inheritance and direct lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.
        |
        -->
        <mirror>
          <id>central</id>
          <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
          <name>nexus  repo</name>
          <url>http://rep-pc.company.ru:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
</settings>
```

Console arguments for maven:

```
--no-plugin-registry --fail-fast --no-plugin-updates --strict-checksums \
--update-snapshots -s C:\Donz\Projects\Maven\settings.xml -f \
C:\Donz\Projects\WebClient\pom.xml install
```

Cache, metadata, indexes were expired, rebuild and renewed for snapshot repo and groups/public. Snapshot-repo was restarted.

If I put missing snapshot files to my local repo maven doesn't report any error.

What is the problem with downloading snapshots from remote repo?

Comment: Have you problem with remote download versions (if it's true than may be you haven't connect to remote repo) or this trouble only for snapshots (than may be snapshots repo didn't setuped properly)?

Comment: Have you checked to access the artifacts via browser instead of taking a look into the files system?

Comment: This trouble only with snapshots. And I don't know how I could mistake with snapshots repo setup - there is only one specific setting for snapshot (repo type) in Nexus. Yes, I checked access via browser. It's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `<activeProfiles><activeProfile>dev</activeProfile></activeProfiles>` inside `<settings>` element.

Comment: Also try this (i have config like this and everything works fine (but i use artifactory) : `<repository><id>public-snapshots</id><name>Local repository for public snapshots group</name><url>http://rep-pc.company.ru:8081/nexus/content/repositories/rep-snapshots</url><snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots></repository>`

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately I have to solve another problem for this moment. When I return to set maven repo I try your advice and post result here.

Comment: Yes, your solution exacty that I was needed!